# Sequences vs Identity columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Is it better to use Sequences in oracle and auto-increment a column using Before insert trigger or to use identity columns as it is available in Oracle 12 c?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either way you're going to be using Sequences. Identity columns in 12c use the same mechanism behind the scenes.

The benefit - the db is managing these objects, and not you.

[image]

The feature was introduced to aid in the migration of systems from places like SQL Server and Sybase ASE where these were popular. Much simpler to migrate as is than create a sequence/trigger pair to maintain going forward.

And that benefit extends to regular Oracle customers as well. The flexibility of the IDENTITY clause includes everything you can set when manually defining a sequence.

Comment: That was spot on.

Comment: And not just flexibility. Fewer database objects for the developers to create and maintain (no more trigger). Tim Hall offers a nice roundup of this feature here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1